# Data uri's - base 64 encoding. Can you do it automatic with a javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64

I have a question about base64 encoding for images. I used base64 for small background images. I convert it with a online base64 tool. And put it directly in the CSS file.

But is there a way. That the base64 encoding go automatic. When i upload the files to the server or when i run the website. Then the small background images in the CSS. Convert automatic to base64 encoding. Do you understand??

Thanks for help!

Comment: You want automatic conversion of images to base64 encoded data:url in css, when you upload files to your server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if I exactly understand your question. However, the `<canvas>` element offers a function named [`.toDataURL()`<sup>help</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas), which converts the contents from the `<canvas>` node into a Base64 encoded string. But that does not make much sense in your case anyway I guess.

Same story for `window.btoa()`. You would need to ordinary transfer the images to the client and then converting them, which does not make any sense. So you would need a tool/script which runs on the server and transfers images as base64. And guess what, it exists.

[supplyJS](https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply)

Using supplyJS, you could create a call like

```
supply.listen('image/jpg', function(payload, filename) {
    jQuery('<img>', {
        src: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + payload
    }).appendTo(document.body);
});

supply.setDealer('/cgi-bin/supply.pl').files({
    images: [
        '/images/foo.jpg',
        '/images/bar.jpg',
        '/images/another.jpg'
    ]
});
```

It will natively convert all images into base64 to transfer them.

Example: http://www.typeofnan.com/lab/mxhr-stream/